# Google Chrome constantly reappears in Dock as new app

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive, dock

Google Chrome keeps reappearing in my Dock as a 'new' app, on its own, every 5-20 seconds. After reaching 2 icons, it continues to appear replacing the older icon.

You can see it happen around 14 seconds mark at this [Screen capture video link](https://streamable.com/6h9yva)

I suspect the bug is connected to the new Drive app that replaced the previous 'back up and sync'. Drive app version: 51.0.15.0 (Intel)

If I open up Drive preferences, it shows a 'launched-app-dot' near those Chrome icons in Dock:
[image: screenshot]

Please, advise.

Comment: Does this thread help you any? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175405/strange-duplicate-chrome-icon-with-a-display-icon-within-in-just-popped-up

Comment: I've seen it, thanks! Unfortunately, not my case